# Managing Too many Columns data in a table in view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a mysql table in which I have 35 fields.
I have to show the list of all the records.
I only want to know that how can I manage all these column in the view file so that the user doesn't have to scroll right to view all the column values that are not displayed when user lands on that page.
Is there any alternative to this problem?
I don't want to use pagination for displaying single record; instead I am using pagination for displaying 10 records per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can suggest you to use "jquery collapse expand" for this. initially you can show the important fields when it is collapse. you can show the all fields when it is expanded.

Comment: Well i have the same idea and thanks for your answer but i wanted to know how can we manage it without javascript and waht was peoples' practice about this situation?

Comment: you can't show the entire fields in a single row without  right scrolling. so you have control the view data in the front end only.. so the only way you can go for this is jquery/JS.